# How to calculate no of days where sales were made in MS excel using sumifs and countifs?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumifs

I am working on an excel sheet where I am required to calculate average number of days the stores in a city were able to make some sales. I am attaching a sample of the table for reference. The values in the cells represent the number of units sold(not relevant to this question).

[image]

Here across NY, two stores are present, and out of the total number of days in consideration (3*2), only 4 days some sales were made, making the average 66%.
Similarly for Paris, there exists only one store which was open across all days.

To arrive at the figures, I tried using nested countifs and SUMIFS , but did not receive the expected results. Also, in some of the older posts, users had suggested to use INDEX MATCH with SUMIFS, but I was not to get accurate results using these.

Can anyone help me to get the correct figures for *Total days*, and *Days with some sale*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SUMPRODUCT SOLUTION

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A$2:A$5=A8)*--(C$2:E$5<>""))
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A$2:A$5=A8)*--(C$2:E$5<>"NO SALE"))
=ROUND(C8/B8,4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works like a charm. Just one question: what if I do $A$2 instead of A$2 (similarly for other references) ? Will it make any difference ? As per my understanding, doing $XX$yy fixes the range across which the search is made for all subsequent lookups.

Answer (score 0):

First, according to your grid NY made sales on 4 of the 6 days. (NY1: Mon, Wed; NY2: Tues, Wed). Thus the average is not 50% but 66%.

Second, to get your formula. Assuming "Place" is in column A. Below is for NY, you can solve for the rest.

Total number of days:
In cell "C9": `=COUNTIF(A2:A4,"=NY") * 3`

Days with sales:
In cell "D9": `=COUNTIF(C2:E2,"<>NO SALE") + COUNTIF(C4:E4,"<>NO SALE")`

Comment: I wrote the exact same code. But it cannot be reciprocated if the number of rows are large. One cannot write countifs N number of times